# Updating gfortran compiler from 4.8 to 4.9

Tags: 14.04, gcc

I have gFortran 4.8.4 on my system. I installed version 4.9 by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.9
```

Everything seemed fine, but if I type `gfortran --version`, it says that it's version 4.8.4 still. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have two gfortran packages installed: `gfortran` plain (version 4.8.4) and `gfortran-4.9` (version 4.9).

When you run `gfortran` in a regular terminal, you're actually running version 4.8.4, as you've noticed. In order to force your system to use the 4.9 version, try running `gfortran-4.9` from the terminal.

---

Now, in theory, you *could* force `gfortran-4.9` to be called from `gfortran`, but this is not recommended. If you want to ignore this warning, do this:

1. Back up and remove the existing `gfortran` binary.

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran.bak
   sudo rm /usr/bin/gfortran
   ```
2. Link `gfortran-4.9` to the old one:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran-4.9 /usr/bin/gfortran
   ```

Note that you will lose this if you actually update the regular `gfortran` package, so keep this in mind.

For a slightly more permanent alteration that runs no risk of breaking your system (with the downside that it only works in a terminal), you could also assign `gfortran` to be an alias of `gfortran-4.9` by running this:

```
echo "alias gfortran=gfortran-4.9" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Restart any Bash sessions, and `gfortran` should run version 4.9